# jQuery Removing ::after css from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have css like:

```
.support-hub .app-detail:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Firebug shows it as

```
.support-hub .app-detail::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

In my code I am doing this:

```
$('.support-hub .app-detail:after').css({'display':'inline'});
```

But that display property is not getting changed.
Pls help. Very less documentation available for :after css manipulation with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution would be to apply the ::after or ::before style to a class(not the main element) and remove the e class

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `after` like this. Technically DOM elements cannot be accessed by the jQuery with this.

Simply try like this

```
$('.support-hub .app-detail').css({'display':'inline'});
```

Or you may use `next` jQuery method or something like this to manipulate the DOM elements.

```
$('.support-hub .app-detail').next().css({'display':'inline'});
```

Please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/21709814#21709814)

Comment: I believe after() is used to insert element.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to your css:

```
.support-hub .app-detail.inline:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline;
    clear: both;
}
```

And you could call the this from javascript:

```
$('.support-hub .app-detail').addClass('');
```